# There are 20 people. Among the 12 months in the year there are 4 months containing exactly 2 birthdays and 4 containing exactly 3 birthdays.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> There are $20$ people. Find the probability that among the $12$ months in the year there are $4$ months containing exactly $2$ birthdays and $4$ containing exactly $3$ birthdays?

I am unable to get from the problem as to whether the $4$ months talked about are overlapping or disjoint? If they are disjoint then what about the remaining $4$ months... Suppose the remaining $4$ months have $0,1,2,3,...14,15$ birthdays then we can possibly use multinomial theorem as
$x_1+x_2+x_3+y_1+y_2+ki=20$ ;$i=0,1,2,...14,15$

Total no of ways becomes (say A): $\binom{19}{4}+\binom{19}{5}+\binom{19}{6}+...+\binom{19}{13}+\binom{19}{14}$

Total no outcomes(D): $12^{20}$

Required probability= $\frac{\binom{12}{4}\times\binom{8}{4}×A}{D}$

But I am not getting the answer. It is given as $1.0604 × 10^{-3}$

Comment: There are $4$ month that each contain exactly $3$ birthdays, and $4$ other months that each contain exactly $2$ birthdays.  That accounts for all $20$ birthdays; the other months contain none.

Comment: Ohh ok. Thanks. The problem has the "each" term missing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question given can be corrected as shown:

> There are $20$ people. Find the probability that among the $12$ months in the year there are $4$ months *each* containing exactly $2$ birthdays and $4$ months *each* containing exactly $3$ birthdays?

So $4\times2 + 4\times3= 20$

Now the total possible outcomes are(n) = $12^{20}$

No of out comes favourable(m) =
$$\binom{12}{4}\times\binom{8}{4}\times\binom{20}{8}\times\left(\frac{8!}{(2!)^4}\right) \times\left (\frac{12!}{(3!)^4}\right)$$

Required probability $= \frac{m}{n} = 1.060420099×10^{-3}$